QEMU/KVM: capturing keyboard shortcuts by the guest operating system
I have installed QEMU/KVM on my Ubuntu and created a new VM.
When trying to switch apps using Alt+Tab or "Show Applications" using Windows key it is captured and interpreted by the host OS system. But I need to use those keys inside guest OS.

I am trying to solve the same problem. When pressing a keyboard shortcut combo, it is sent to both the host and the guest. Did you manage to solve it ?
